# Best practices of attaching a promise after rejection

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Say we have functions `A` and `B` that return promises. `B` should be called only in case `A` rejects, and I need to log both success and error results of both promises. First, I came up with this piece of code:

```js
const A = () => Promise.reject(true);
const B = () => Promise.resolve(true);

A()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('A success');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('A error');
    return B();
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('B success');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('B error');
  });
```

It works fine in case `A` rejects. In case `A` resolves, however, I'm getting one additional `B success` message, which is perfectly expected but which I do not need in this case.

One possible solution I came up with is attaching the `.then()` for `B()` right next to the `B()` call.

```js
const A = () => Promise.reject(true);
const B = () => Promise.resolve(true);

A()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('A success');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('A error');

    return B().then(() => {
      console.log('B success');
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('B error');
  });
```

This of course solves my problem but it feels like more of a hack than a solution. I believe there are better approaches and practices for composing this kind of promise chains.

Comment: Your second approach looks perfectly fine to me. If you want it to look cleaner you could switch some of the `.then`s with `await`s. If the chain becomes more complicated, you can extract into functions, eg `handleAError`

Comment: Not a hack, that's basically how you do it if you use explicit promise callbacks. (Side note: You mean "if A is fulfilled," not "if A resolves" when contrasting with A rejecting. I write about promise terminology here: https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite fine. However, notice that your `catch` handlers also run if any of the previous `then` handlers did cause an error, not only if `A()` or `B()` errored. I therefore recommend [using `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572):

```
A().then(() => {
  console.log('A success');
}, e => {
  console.log('A error', e);
  return B().then(() => {
    console.log('B success');
  }, e => {
    console.log('B error', e);
  });
});
```